# ceph octopus installation using cephadm

Tags: ceph

I tried installing ceph octopus using cephadm. Few issues as I see it(non production):

- Defining public and cluster network
- Defining osd properties, say multiple osd's per device
- Monitoring does not come up in the dashboard by default.

I am using centos7 single BM, single free disk. Not the ideal situation, but for test purposes, should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are your questions?
After setting up the bootstrap node you can define cluster network (before any OSDs are created). Multiple OSDs per device won't be possible because it's not a production environment and hence not documented. You'll have to do that manually on each node with `ceph-volume lvm` command.
There are some basic monitoring values in the dashboard but you can enhance it with grafana (https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/mgr/dashboard/#dashboard-grafana).